# AgGrid Clipboard: Include group header

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a table with some grouped columns that I'm trying to enable Copy&Paste for.

I'm trying to get the grouped headers to be included in the Clipboard, like we have on the Export functionality by setting columnGroups to true.

Like so:

#### Original Table

[image]

#### Clipboard table

```
Athlete Details      Athlete Details      Athlete Details
Name                 Country              Age
Michael Phelps       United States        23
Michael Phelps       United States        19
Michael Phelps       United States        27
```

The problem is that when I include the headers, I'm only getting the column headers (i.e. Name, Country, Age).

I looked through the documentation and was not able to achieve this.
I figured I could use `processHeaderForClipboard` combined with `sendToClipboard`to achieve this by collecting the each columns parent header into an array, then joining it and prepending the return string.

```
processHeaderForClipboard(params) {
    this.columnGroupNames.push(params.column.parent.originalColumnGroup.colGroupDef.headerName);
    console.log(this.columnGroupNames);
    return params.column.getColDef().field;
}

sendToClipboard(params) {
    return this.columnGroupNames.join('\t') + '\n' + params.data;
}
```

However, as you can see in this Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/RpiTxEIa90Gq31jr), I don't have access to the component's variables.

Has anyone been able to include the Grouped Column headers in their Clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

I see you can access the component's variables like this -

```
[processHeaderForClipboard]="processHeaderForClipboard.bind(this)"
[sendToClipboard]="sendToClipboard.bind(this)"
```

The current logic keeps on adding to the `this.columnGroupNames`.

Once you reset the values and stop adding dupes, your code should work.